# If a hostile creature casts the Suggestion spell on you, can your allies cause the spell to end by attacking you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, mind-control

Say a member of the party has had Suggestion cast on them by a hostile creature.

Can the other party members end the spell by attacking the affected party member?
Or is that condition for the spell ending restricted only to the hostile spellcaster and their allies?

Comment: Related: [Does a Charmed person have to know who damaged them for the spell to end?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/153250/52137)

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: It does indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### This does not work.

This is spelled out explicitly in the spell description of [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion):

> If you or any of your companions damage the target, the spell ends.

This is the end condition. “Companions” is defined in relation to the caster. Since your allies are not companions of the hostile creature, they cannot end the spell by damaging you.

This ruling should cover most situations, but [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121138/62294) goes into greater detail about how we are to understand what a companion is, and may help if ever it is not clear.